# When using "Async" Methods are there Threads of the Threadpool blocked?

Tags: .net, threadpool

AFAIK the following is true:

It is not a good idea to block a thread of the threadpool for a long time (because they are limited).
Tasks use threads of the threadpool and are therefore for short term, not long blocking actions.
Async methods (like FindAsync in Entity Framework) return a task you can wait (or await) for to receive the result.

What I dont't understand:

If I call e.g. FindAsync is there simply a task created that runs on a ThreadPool thread and invokes the non async find method (blocking the ThreadPool Thread until the find returns)? Or are there deeper operating system mechanisms involved and a ThreadPool Thread is used not before the Find method Returns?

The Reason:

If variant 1 holds true, there is no difference between calling the FindAsync method or starting a task myself and calling the Find method in it.

If variant 2 holds true, there is a difference, because starting a task calling the Find method will long term block a ThreadPool Thread, while calling FindAsync will not.

Comment: Stephen Cleary wrote an excellent piece [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) which you might want to read. And bear in mind the existence of `TaskCompletionSource` - that specifically exists to allow `Tasks` to be created which definitely are *not* running on the threadpool.

Comment: In this specific case, the SqlClient underneath offers true asynchronous execution without using background threads. IO (including network calls) is inherently asynchronous in Windows. Thread blocking is *emulated*. ADO.NET uses IO completion ports to talk to the database server and resume processing once the response is received. Other providers (eg MySQL's ) fake asynchrony by starting a new thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is not a good idea to block a thread of the threadpool for a long time (because they are limited).

The thread pool will respond to a "loss" of a thread by injecting a new one, so blocking a thread pool thread for a long time is not particularly problematic. (Of course, it would be better *not* to block a thread pool thread in the first place).

> Tasks use threads of the threadpool and are therefore for short term, not long blocking actions.

This is only true of Delegate Tasks that are scheduled to the thread pool. A lot of the old (.NET 4-era) documentation around tasks assume that you're using Delegate Tasks scheduled on the thread pool, so this is a common misunderstanding of tasks *in general*.

In the modern world, Delegate Tasks are much more rare; Promise Tasks are more common these days. Promise Tasks just act as a "signal" meaning "something completed." For more about Delegate Tasks and Promise Tasks, see my blog posts on [Task Overview](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html) and [Task status](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-3-status.html).

(Also, Delegate Tasks *can* be scheduled to any kind of `TaskScheduler`; they're not just for thread pool tasks).

> Async methods (like FindAsync in Entity Framework) return a task you can wait (or await) for to receive the result.

There's a distinction here that needs to be made between methods that use `async` for their implementation, and [TAP methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) that end in `*Async` and are intended for use with `await`. Those two commonly go together, but not always.

`async` always returns a Promise Task, never a Delegate Task. Also, it's generally *expected* that an `*Async` method will return a Promise Task, but some methods return Delegate Tasks instead. When methods do this, I call it "fake asynchrony", because it's just synchronously blocking another thread.

> If I call e.g. FindAsync is there simply a task created that runs on a ThreadPool thread and invokes the non async find method (blocking the ThreadPool Thread until the find returns)?

Not in the general case. Pretty much all `*Async` methods provided by .NET return Promise Tasks.

> Or are there deeper operating system mechanisms involved and a ThreadPool Thread is used not before the Find method Returns?

The Promise Tasks returned by most .NET `*Async` methods use I/O Completion Ports under the hood, as I describe in my article [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

> If variant 1 holds true, there is no difference between calling the FindAsync method or starting a task myself and calling the Find method in it.
>
> If variant 2 holds true, there is a difference, because starting a task calling the Find method will long term block a ThreadPool Thread, while calling FindAsync will not.

In the general case, you want to use the `*Async` methods, which avoid blocking any threads at all.

However, as others have noted in the comments, this particular example of Entity Framework is a bit more complex. Entity Framework itself is async-agnostic; it builds on top of "providers", which may or may not support asynchrony. Microsoft's SqlClient provider does support asynchrony, so `FindAsync` talking to SQL Server will properly work asynchronously. However, other providers may not (as of this writing, SQLite is a common provider that does not support asynchrony), and for those providers, "asynchronous" APIs like `FindAsync` are actually implemented by blocking a thread pool thread.

So, in the general case, "variant 2" would be true; but for your particular example of `FindAsync`, they are both true.

Comment: Thank you. That were exactly the hints I needed. :-)